# How does findViewWithTag() work?

Tags: android

I looked into android platform framework source code, and found its implementation [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java). Here're code fragments:

```
public final View findViewWithTag(Object tag) {
    if (tag == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewWithTagTraversal(tag);
}

protected View findViewWithTagTraversal(Object tag) {
    if (tag != null && tag.equals(mTag)) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It seems that it merely compares the given tag with its own tag and then returns itself or null. Nothing **traversal** happens. Then how does it work to find any child view with a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View` base-class does not have children. It is [`ViewGroup`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java) which may have children and if you look at the definitions for that you will see they are more complicated.